# iptables -forward mail server port from inside lan to outside lan

Tags: networking, iptables, squid

ive local server with squid to manage my lan , it got 2 NICs and my mail server its outside the lan what i need here when users ty to connect and send email through NIC-1 its should fwd request to NIC2 which is connected to internet ( port 25,110 )
any tips to fwd by iptables 
regards

Comment: please update your post with IP address information and a more detailed description of what you want to accomplish. In its current state it is too vague to be answered meaningfully.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that `eth0` is the internal interface and `eth1` is the external interface.

Enable IP forwarding:

```
echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
```

and try something like this:

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp -i eth0 --dport 25 -j DNAT --to-destination <eth1_IP>:25
iptables -A FORWARD -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 25 -m state --state NEW,RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
```

Do the same for port 110.